# Как можно переименовать элемент в ListView ?

Tags: c#

Собственно как его переименовать, желательно не меня позицию в списке.

Answer (score 1):

Если имеется коллекция текстовых данных, которые отображаются в виде ListView, и есть потребность менять эти данные, то ListView - неподходящий для этих целей контрол. Правильнее взять [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx), который можно настроить так, чтобы он выглядел, как ListView. Также можно взять обертку над ListView - [objectlistview](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html), которая позволяет редактировать данные.

Вдогонку: [Create a ListView with Editable Cells](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms745183.aspx).